# Best practice for preloading and caching images (AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimageview, afnetworking

I was wondering what is the best practice for this very common action:
Say i have a collection view, and each cell of this collection view has an imageView that receives a url for an image.

The images are large, so i want to preload all the images in advance (or say 5 in advance).
I'm using AFNetworking imageView Category.

So here's what i did - creating a temp UIImageView and set the url to it each iteration, but it seems not to be working right. (the images still takes time to show up, while i want it to be instantly, and if i close the internet connection, the images do not load from cache).

```
- (void)preloadGalleryImages {

for (GalleryItem *item in _galleryItems) {
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [tempImageView setImageWithURL:item.imageURL placeholderImage:IMAGE(@"placegolder")];
    }
}
```

}

Thanks,

Comment: Tried this? https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

There is a universal way of preheating images in collection views that was implemented in one of the Apple [PhotosKit samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/SamplePhotosApp_AAPLAssetGridViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-SamplePhotosApp_AAPLAssetGridViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8). You can anticipate user actions and fetch images that might soon appear on the display (that are close to the viewport). This feature is implemented in [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) and [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager/wiki/Image-Preheating-Guide).